# Occasional SOAP endpoint not found failure: EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: soap, fuel, sdk

I'm using the Fuel SDK to manage subscribers on in lists. We are using synchronous calls to patch subscribers and tend to call it pretty heavily, as we loop through the list of our subscribers and call the Subscriber Patch to make sure they are up-to-date.  We probably call it 400-600 times per send, and send about 10x per day (probably should change to use the subscriber import functionality...)

Every so often, maybe once per day, we get a failure exception from the ET_Subscriber.Patch() call of the following:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
>   listening at https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 68.232.203.67:443

What's interesting is that it works fine if I take that request and replay it, so I don't think it's anything in the input of the patch.  There aren't any other failures from subsequent SOAP calls that we make around that time.

Has anyone else had this issue? Salesforce support seems to be lost since I don't have the exact SOAP input/output due to it being hidden away by the SDK.

Comment: Sounds like a timeout. Is it a large payload?

Comment: It's _busy_, you need to [retry the call](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-retry-pattern-with-exponential-back). This implies a scalability issue in either the client or the server (sounds like the latter) and you could say that it shouldn't happen but It Is What It Is (tm).